# Setting up Jetty Runner with custom Cert in Docker Build File

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, docker, logstash

I am currently creating a Docker file for building our webapp in java, and I am running into an issue in regards to having to use a custom .cert key to log over SSL using logstash-logback-forwarder, while the webapp itself needs to do SSL connections (connecting to SOAP SSL). The thing is, I am able to log over SSL, and the webapp can use the SOAP API securely fine (it has always been able to do this), but I can't do both at the same time.

For starters, here are the relevant parts of my docker build file

```
ADD logstash-forwarder.crt /root/logstash-forwarder.crt
RUN (cd /root && /usr/java/latest/bin/keytool -import -file logstash-forwarder.crt -alias logstash -storepass SOMEPASS -noprompt -keystore logstash.keystore)
```

This adds the crt file, and then uses the keytool to import into the keyStore. I am using logstash-logback-forwarder, which uses the standard `SSLSocketFactory` (i.e. https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/blob/master/src/main/java/net/logstash/logback/appender/SSLLogstashTcpSocketAppender.java)

Then I run my java site (through jetty-webrunner), using this command

```
CMD java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/root/logback.xml \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=SOMEPASS \ 
  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks \ 
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=logstash.keystore \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=SOMEPASS \
  -server -ea -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
  -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled \
  -Xmx2048M -jar jetty-runner-9.2.3.v20140905.jar \
  --port 8080 \
  --lib "/root/lib" \
  --config jetty.xml \
  jetty-web.xml
```

Now with the following command, the secure logging works fine over SSL, the problem is, the webapp is no longer able to securely connect to a SOAP API that it needs to use, I get the following error (java stacktrace provided)

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1471)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:212)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:936)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:871)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
```

Now obviously if I remove the SSL entirely (obviously the logging will stop working), by doing this

```
CMD java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/root/logback.xml \
  -server -ea -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
  -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled \
  -Xmx2048M -jar jetty-runner-9.2.3.v20140905.jar \
  --port 8080 \
  --lib "/root/lib" \
  --config jetty.xml \
  jetty-web.xml
```

The SOAP apis via axis works fine, but the SSL logging doesn't. I am aware that you are able to combine keystores using the `keytool`, however I havn't gotten my head around to it (its a lot more complicated than passing the .crt file with a single flag that most non-java apps tend to do). How would you import the .keystore so it works correctly (and what would the equivalent docker commands be?)

The server is running JDK 8

Comment: Bug opened to make SSL configurable in `SSLLogstashTcpSocketAppender` directly (as in the `logback.xml` file)  https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/issues/57